# How to categorize records in groups in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Here is a same schema with data,

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
  id       int            PRIMARY KEY,
  name     varchar(30)
);  
CREATE TABLE emp (
  id       int            PRIMARY KEY,
  name     varchar(50),
  group_id int            REFERENCES groups
);  
INSERT INTO groups(id,name) VALUES
  (1, 'Managers'),
  (2, 'Teachers'),
  (3, 'Cleaners'),
  (4, 'Drivers');
INSERT INTO emp(id,name,group_id) VALUES
  (1,'john',1),
  (2,'Smith',1),
  (3,'Evank',2),
  (4,'Doe',3),
  (5,'Jane',4);
```

Now I need to categorize groups by the title of `Site` and have the following result:
I want to count all `managers` and `teachers` as `site1`, `cleansers` as `site2`, `Drivers` as `site3` and so on.

```
Site      Employees  
Site1         3  
Site2         1  
Site3         1
```

Comment: as a side note, in PostgreSQL we don't use `varchar()` like that, `text` is also stored on the table, except it doesn't have a length constraint. They're both stored internally in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "sites" field in your SQL statements.

I did the following to solve your problem:

(You'll notice that I've taken many more fields than are necessary to do the operation - it's so that you understand where the data is coming from. I often find it very helpful to include far more fields than required in my initial attempts at formulating SQL and then I pare them down as required by the problem!).

```
WITH emp_group_join AS
(
  SELECT e.id AS eid, e.name AS ename, e.group_id AS egid, 
         g.id AS gid, g.name AS gname
  FROM emp e
  JOIN groups g ON 
     e.group_id = g.id
),
sites AS
(
  SELECT egj.*,
    CASE 
      -- This is necessary to distinguish between Managers + Teachers
      -- and other categories of worker - of course, if you add a site
      -- field, you may not have to do this!

      WHEN gname = 'Managers' THEN 'White Collar'
      WHEN gname = 'Teachers' THEN 'White Collar'
      ELSE gname
    END AS work_type
  FROM emp_group_join egj
)
SELECT work_type, COUNT(work_type) FROM sites
GROUP BY work_type 
ORDER BY work_type DESC;
```

and the result is:

```
  work_type   | count 
--------------+-------
 White Collar |     3
 Drivers      |     1
 Cleaners     |     1
(3 rows)
```

This is how to do it using a sub`SELECT` (same result):

```
SELECT work_type, COUNT(work_type) AS wt_count
FROM
(
  SELECT e.group_id, 
         g.id, 
         g.name,
         CASE
           WHEN g.name = 'Managers' THEN 'White Collar'
           WHEN g.name = 'Teachers' THEN 'White Collar'
           ELSE g.name
         END AS work_type
  FROM emp e
    JOIN groups g ON 
    e.group_id = g.id
) AS join_tab
GROUP BY work_type
ORDER BY wt_count DESC;
```

You could try running the `WITH` clause `SELECT` and/or the sub`SELECT` statements on their own to see in detail what's happening! p.s. +1 for providing DDL and DML!

Answer (score 0):

You can use union operator to achieve this like below:

```
SELECT 'Site1' Site, COUNT(id) Employees FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM emp 
  WHERE group_id IN (1,2) 
  GROUP By group_id,id
) AS q1 
UNION 
SELECT 'Site' || group_id - 1 Site, COUNT(id) 
FROM emp 
WHERE group_id NOT IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY group_id,id 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: It works but it's ugly! :-) Concatenating an `INTEGER` to a string? Oooh, wouldn't be allowed in my shop! p.s. in future could you please format your answers something like I have done - makes them far easier to read, and you'll likely get more upvotes that way!

Comment: I know its ugly, but that's how the solution is written in question. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yes, it "works"... just like I could get from New York to LA on the back of a donkey or in a Ferrari - which would you prefer? Check out my sub`SELECT` solution - also works without such chicanery.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this in your case is to alter the group table and put the data on that. That all said, there is nothing particularly wrong with @Vérace's idea if this is a one-off query. But normally the mapping itself is data and not something you want to maintain in a query.

```
ALTER TABLE groups
  ADD COLUMN site_name text;

UPDATE groups
  SET site_name = 'site1'
  WHERE name IN ('Managers', 'Teachers');
UPDATE groups
  SET site_name = 'site2'
  WHERE name IN ('Cleaners');
UPDATE groups
  SET site_name = 'site3'
  WHERE name IN ('Drivers');
```

Also makes your query simplier.

```
SELECT site_name,count(*)
FROM groups AS g
JOIN emp
  AS e ON e.group_id = g.id
GROUP BY site_name
ORDER BY site_name;

 site_name | count 
-----------+-------
 site1     |     3
 site2     |     1
 site3     |     1
(3 rows)
```